# I want to write a JavaScript program for a simple counter

Tags: javascript, counter

I wrote this code for my simple counter but it's not running as it should. It is supposed to stop decrementing when the count gets to 0. Please help me check what could be wrong.

```js
let count = 0;

let displayCount = document.getElementById("count")

let incrementElement = document.getElementById("increment");
let decrementElement = document.getElementById("decrement");
let resetElement = document.getElementById("reset");

function increment() {
  let count = 0
  count++;
}

function decrement() {
  displayCount.textContent = count;
  if (count !== 0) {
    count--;
  }
}

function reset() {
  displayCount.textContent = count;
  count = 0;
}

displayCount = incrementElement.addEventListener("click", increment);
decrementElement.addEventListener("click", decrement);
resetElement.addEventListener("click", reset);
```

I wrote the code above but when I click the buttons it goes forward before doing what it is supposed to do. For example, if the count is 4 and I click the decrement button, it goes to 5 before going back to 4 then 3, 2, 1, 0.

Comment: pls include all relevant html

Comment: `function increment() {
let count = 0
count++;
}` is wrong, that is never going to increment count since you redeclare it.

Comment: You display count before you change the value. Read the code out loud. I set the element's text to count. If count is not zero I subtract one. So when count is 4. You click the button, it updates the text to 4 and then you subtract one and the variable count is 3, but the UI still shows 4.

Comment: your increment function is wrong, your reset function is wrong and your decrement function is wrong. fix those and it should work. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is useful for you :)

```html
<div>
        <div id="count">0</div>
        <button id="increment">increment</button>
        <button id="decrement">decrement</button>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 0;
        var displayCount = document.getElementById("count");

        var incrementElement = document.getElementById("increment");
        var decrementElement = document.getElementById("decrement");
        var resetElement = document.getElementById("reset");

        incrementElement.addEventListener('click',function () {
            if (count < "1") {
                count++;
                displayCount.innerHTML = count;
            } else {
                count++;
                displayCount.innerHTML = count;
            }   
        });
        decrementElement.addEventListener('click',function () {
            if (count != "0") {
                count--;
                displayCount.innerHTML = count;
            }   
        });
        resetElement.addEventListener('click',function () {
            displayCount.innerHTML = "0";   
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
let count = 0;

let displayCount = document.getElementById("count")

let incrementElement = document.getElementById("increment");
let decrementElement = document.getElementById("decrement");
let resetElement = document.getElementById("reset");

function increment() {
  count++;
  displayCount.textContent = count;
}

function decrement() {
  if (count > 0) {
      count--;
  }
  displayCount.textContent = count;
}

function reset() {
  count = 0;
  displayCount.textContent = count;
}

incrementElement.addEventListener("click", increment);
decrementElement.addEventListener("click", decrement);
resetElement.addEventListener("click", reset);
```

I removed the `let count = 0` inside `increment` because otherwise you mess up with closures, and also removed the assignment

```
displayCount = incrementElement.addEventListener("click", increment);
```

because it was incorrect. Then you want to set the textContent of the HTML tag **after** the math operation. The rest looks fine, welcome to Javascript!

Answer (score 1):

I made a basic one, but since I didn't have your html code, I started over.

```html
<h1 id="count"></h1>
<button type="button" id="inc">Incriment</button>
<button type="button" id="dec">Decrement</button>
<button type="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
<script src="script.js"></script> <!-- You will have to change the script decleration based on your js file. If you are just using your html file, remove the src decleration and add the js code in between the <script></script> blocks -->
```

```js
let count = document.querySelector("#count");
let incButton = document.querySelector("#inc");
let decButton = document.querySelector("#dec");
let resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
var num = 0;
count.innerText = num;

incButton.addEventListener("click", increment);
decButton.addEventListener("click", decrement);
resetButton.addEventListener("click", reset);

function increment() {
  num++;
  count.innerText = num;
}

function decrement() {
  if(num > 0) {
    num--;
  }
  count.innerText = num;
}

function reset() {
  num = 0;
  count.innerText = num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        let count = 0;

        let displayCount = document.getElementById("count")

        let incrementElement = document.getElementById("increment");
        let decrementElement = document.getElementById("decrement");
        let resetElement = document.getElementById("reset");

        function increment() {
            count++;
            displayCount.innerText = count;
        }
        function decrement() {
            if (count !== 0) {
                count--;
            }
            displayCount.innerText = count;
        }
        function reset() {
            count = 0;
            displayCount.innerText = count;
        }

        incrementElement.addEventListener("click", increment);
        decrementElement.addEventListener("click", decrement);
        resetElement.addEventListener("click", reset);
```

If you want to display a variable, first you have to set the variable and then change the HTML content.
also you didn't have to set the listener for the increment as a variable because all it will do is give you a error

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal, verifiable example.

```js
let count = 0

const countElement = document.getElementById("count")
const incrementElement = document.getElementById("increment")
const decrementElement = document.getElementById("decrement")
const resetElement = document.getElementById("reset")

function increment() {
  count++
  countElement.textContent = count
}

function decrement() {
  if (count > 0) count--
  countElement.textContent = count
}

function reset() {
  count = 0
  countElement.textContent = count
}

incrementElement.addEventListener("click", increment)
decrementElement.addEventListener("click", decrement)
resetElement.addEventListener("click", reset)
```

```html
<button id="decrement">➖</button>
<span id="count">0</span>
<button id="increment">➕</button>
<br>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```